# Connection spikes when connected (only) through wireless

Tags: windows-7, networking, windows-8, wireless-networking

I've been experiencing HUGE spikes while connected trough wireless in my home, and I just can't figure out what is happening. I've had this problem with my previous computer too, I just bought a new one and the problem persists, so I'm out of ideas. Here's the details:

- Both computers are notebooks, models (new) Dell XPS 15z & (new) MSI GS70 Stealth Pro.
- <del>I can only really "feel" the problem while online gaming (particularly DOTA 2).</del>
- Everything works fine and smooth while connected through Ethernet cable.
- Problem persists in other wireless networks (different places, different routers and ISP).
- Both computers have NVIDIA video cards (5xxM and 870M).
- First computer had Windows 7, second is running Windows 8.1.
- Both computers get quite hot while playing.
- <del>The spikes occur every couple of minutes or so.</del>
- WI-Fi cards:  Intel Centrino Advanced-N 6230 (Dell) and Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260 (MSI).

That's all i can think of. I've searched around the internet for information regarding these cases and i remember finding a huge forum thread in Dell's forums, lots of users having similar problems, some solved it, some didn't. I can't find similar threads or information regarding the second computer though.

What I've tried:

- Different combinations of drivers for wireless cards.
- Different routers and ISP.
- Different (physical) locations.
- Huge external ventilators.

Thanks a lot, if I should add more information of the case please let me know.

Edit 1: After looking carefully I found out that the spikes occur weather I'm playing something or not. I went back to the basics and left a "ping -t" command running for solid 20 minutes. The ouput showed clearly the spikes happening, so it's not related to computer usage. I also found out that spikes occur every 120 seconds (average, since the tool i used to measure wasn't perfect, from 118 seconds to 122 second every single time), or tow minutes. Hope this information helps, I'll continue looking.

Comment: Have you tried disabling all power saving options including U-APSD?

Comment: Ok, I think I found the problem. Apparently it was related to the router. It's kind of late so I will edit and answer the question tomorrow for future references. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, reporting back. I finally tracked down the problem. Turns out it was related with the router, an Arris TG862 provided by the ISP (VTR Chile). I remember having the same problem at a friend's house a while ago, different router but the same company, so the problem *may* happen in other company provided routers.

What worked for me was:

- Changing Arris TG862 broadcast type to 802.11g.
- Changing Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260 broadcast type to 802.11g (same).
- Changing NAT type of the router from RouterWithNAT to bridge.
- Disabling Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260 Bakground scan. (Information in how to do so [here](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Windows-8-and-8-1/SOLUTION-latency-spikes-and-network-unstability-on-Intel-WLAN/td-p/1461487)).

Please note that in my particular experience (different from the link I just shared), the spikes occurred every 2 minutes (120s), and the spikes were a lot higher (between 1700ms and 3900ms, sometimes even a lost packet).

I hope that this experience can be of any help to someone out there, saw a lot of unresolved posts related to these wifi cards around the web.

Regards